Custom UserDetailsService Is Not Being Called
I'm trying to configure Spring Security for the first time today, and I am struggling to implement a custom UserDetailsService. I was able to get this working just fine using the InMemoryUserDetailsManager described in this article: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web.
When implementing my own UserDetailsService, however, the password authentication simply fails with no stacktrace. I don't think loadUserByUsername is even being called, because the logging statements do not execute.
Right now I'm just trying to get it working with a simple dummy user:
Here is my implementation of UserDetailsService:
@Service
public class AuthApiUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthApiUserDetailsService.class);

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        logger.debug("Loading user by username");
        if (!"user".equals(username)) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        logger.debug("Loaded user: " + username);
        logger.info("This is the testing UserDetails service. Do a real implementation later.");
        return User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("user").password("password").roles("USER").build();
    }
}

Here is my WebSecurityConfig:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers("/dashboard").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
            )
            .formLogin((form) -> form
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            )
            .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new AuthApiUserDetailsService();
    }

}

For what it's worth, I am getting these messages relating to UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration on application startup:
   UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider,org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService,org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManagerResolver,org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' authApiUserDetailsService, userDetailsService (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' (OnClassCondition)
         - AnyNestedCondition 1 matched 2 did not; NestedCondition on UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.MissingAlternativeOrUserPropertiesConfigured.PasswordConfigured @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.security.user.password) did not find property 'password'; NestedCondition on UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.MissingAlternativeOrUserPropertiesConfigured.NameConfigured @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.security.user.name) did not find property 'name'; NestedCondition on UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.MissingAlternativeOrUserPropertiesConfigured.MissingAlternative @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted classes 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository', 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.OpaqueTokenIntrospector', 'org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository' (UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.MissingAlternativeOrUserPropertiesConfigured)


I am also getting a TRACE log message on startup showing a ProviderNotFoundException:
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:234)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:231)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)

Been trying to figure this out for a while, and it seems like a lot of the other answers relating to this topic on SO are dated, and were of little use to my situation.
Has anyone been able to figure this out?

After looking a bit deeper into the documentation, I found the answer. I had to expose AuthenticationManager as a @Bean, as described in the docs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/index.html
If you want to use a custom UserDetailsService, you must expose AuthenticationManager as a Bean. You must also set the custom UserDetailService on the DaoAuthenticationProvider by calling setUserDetailService as I do below.
Here is the changes to WebSecurityConfig that worked:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers("/dashboard").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
            )
            .formLogin((form) -> form
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            )
            .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
        MyCustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService,
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

}

